# How to wait for the page to load before scraping it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, urllib2

I want to extract the HTML from a webpage:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('https://www.example.com')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
fullhtml = response.read()
```

I tried with "ulrllib2" but since the page is built dynamically, the HTML content is empty.

Is there a way to wait for the javascript to load?

Comment: Use a crawler that executes javascript or identify the loaded parts (urls) by hand and fetch them.

Comment: urllib2 or nothing else in Python core will execute javascript, anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this http://phantomjs.org/ . Most websites are javascript based and php or python can not execute them. I think this library will be the best you can get.